# Background image that scales on a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

The [wetransfer](https://www.wetransfer.com/) website often has background images that scale when you resize the browser. I would like to achieve the same effect in the simplest possible way. In other words if I drag the bottom corner of the browser window I would like the background image to change accordingly in size.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this as explained in this [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

From the tutorial, the easy CSS way of doing this is to use the `background-size` property.

```
html {
        background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

Cover lets the image stretch while keeping aspect ratio, so that one dimension of the containing area is fully used. Alternative values are contain, which stretches the image with its aspect ratio to completely fit into the area, or 100% 100% which stretches the image while destroying aspect ratio.

You may also want to take a look at the CSS 3 reference at [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: Is it okay to give `html` a background? Would `body` be better?

Comment: You can use any. However, I quote from the tutorial: `We'll use the html element (better than body as it's always at least the height of the browser window)`

Comment: This is fine, but if you need to fade between images like WeTransfer does, you'll need to use something other than a background image on the html/body elements - such as a fixed div with width/height 100%

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to make use of JS. CSS3 will do it for you:

```
html {
        background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: This resembles another answer quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks you! Didn't see the others posted the same at the same time? Delete it?

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a jQuery full screen content slider that utilises full screen images so I have researched in this quiet a lot.

After browsing through countless tutorials that claims to result in a full screen background image, I found an excellent article which describes how to achieve this with about four different techniques - and it's so easy you can do it in about 10 minutes.

Here is the link to the article: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

And just for reference, here is the link to the slider I made: http://hieroishere.com/fullscreenslider/

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is this- no CSS3 or HTML5 required:

```
img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT**:

Just realized that your question pertains to background images- so you can use this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: And this will resize the image dynamically as the user resizes the browser?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Giving 100% 100% will make the size of the background image to 100% of the width and height of the "background positioning area"- so on resize of browser, the image will resize. Read in detail here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size